# Having trouble resetting unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

https://i.imgur.com/El9iCsP.gifv

Above is a gif of what is happening. The game is resetting fine when ever I'm just pressing the reset button however when the player actually dies (collides with a wall) the game doesn't re-initiate. Basically I'm making a kind of speed runner game for a college project (really quick hack together) but it is also my first time using Unity. From what I gather the issue is due to me creating a GameControl class to access the gameOver variable from the player class however I'm not entirely sure how to fix this.

**GameControl:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameControl instance;
    public bool gameOver = false;
    public float scrollSpeed;
    public float scrollIncrease;
    public float startTime;
    public Text timerText;

    public void resetGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else if(instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        startTime = Time.time;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (gameOver == false)
        {
            float t = Time.time - startTime;
            string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
            string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");
            timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
            scrollSpeed -= scrollIncrease;
        }
        else
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Player:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class player : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jump;
    public float jumps = 0;
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    void Update()
    {

        if (GameControl.instance.gameOver == false)
        {
            float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveHorizontal * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && jumps < 2)
            {
                jumps++;
                rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jump));
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "obstacle" || collision.gameObject.name == "Left Boundry")
        {
            GameControl.instance.gameOver = true;
        }
        else if(collision.gameObject.tag == "floor")
        {
            jumps = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware, what `SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);` should do, but I assume it does not reinitialize the static instance of your `GameControl` class. Therefore `gameOver` isn't reset and stays `true`.

To solve that, you could add an `init` method to your GameControl class, which initializes all members and is called on reset.

Answer (score 0):

When the collision is detected, you set `GameControl.instance.gameOver` to `true`.

After that, the `if (gameOver == false)` inside `Update()` of the `GameControl` class executes the `Time.timeScale=0`, which means that you basically pause the game, instead of resetting it.

And from the code you posted, nothing else happens when `gameOver` is `true`.

You should switch `Time.timeScale=0` with a call to the method that resets your game (i.e.: the same one you're using when the Reset button shown in the gif is pressed). Or do both if that's really your intention.

Comment: Thanks man, didn't even realise time.timescale=0 stopped the entire run time. Literally got rid of it and it worked fine. I think what i wanted to do  was stop the timer and physics from running which doesn't really make any sense now.

Comment: Well, if you wanted to stop physics update, then yes, setting `timeScale` to 0 is the way to do that (i.e.: `FixedUpdate()` won't be called at all on any script). Anyway, `Update()` still gets called when the time scale is 0. Don't forget to tag the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.